# Leer datos de json a java

Tags: java, json

Tengo este fichero que querio transformalo en un array de objeto persona. Mi problema es que dentro del jsonObject hay un array

```
"name": "Dennis Jennings", 
"gender": "male", 
"age": 23, 
"longitude": 153.671386, 
"eyeColor": "blue", 
"latitude": 13.166579, 
"_id": "5df2d400a48a9be68b6a8448", 
"friends": [
  {
    "id": 0, 
    "name": "Melba Foley"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Talley Griffin"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "name": "Arline Alston"
  }
], 
"isActive": true
```

aca les dejo el link completo : https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfIbgekmdK?indent=2

Comment: Según el modelo, la clase `Persona` debería tener un `ArrayList` con objetos del tipo `Friends` donde meterías la clave `friends` del JSON.

Comment: Que datos son los que quieres obtener para cada objeto persona ?

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco lioso pero no complicado, lo primero que debes de hacer es obtener los "pojos" para mapear ese json (los pojos son clases javas que sirve para convertir el json en objeto java), eso lo puedes hacer con esta página http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ahí pegas el json del link https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfIbgekmdK?indent=2 y automaticamente te generar los "pojos", te lo descargas en zip y añades las clases al proyecto.
Y para convertir el json en java se utiliza la librería "gson", la puedes importar en el pom.xml con maven, el método a usar sería fromJson.

Un ejemplo podría ser así:

```
String json = "{\"id\":46,\"nombre\":\"Miguel\",\"empresa\":\"Autentia\"}";    
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Persona persona = gson.fromJson(json, Persona.class);
```

Te dejo un enlace donde viene lo que te he explicado con ejemplos
https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2012/09/17/gson-java-json/

Saludos.